# PHP Receber o ID de um valor via select option

Tags: php, html, sql

Opa, pessoal, eu estou desenvolvendo um código e faz dias que estou nessa parte;
Eu preciso obter um valor para registra-lo como ID de uma tabela.

Essa parte do código funciona perfeitamente. Ele demonstra um dropdown do que eu preciso. Mas eu preciso enviar o id vinculado ao "time", infelizmente não está enviando.
Isso é um select dinamico, tudo que eu preciso é pegar o ID de um dos times.
Alguém conseguiria me ajudar? obrigadoo!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os seus erros estão justamente "na parte que está funcionando".

O 1o problema (pode ser apenas falha ao colocar a pergunta) é que falta a TAG `select` com um `name` envolvendo o seu option group. Se isso estiver em falta no seu código vc não poderá fazer isso:

```php
if (isset($_POST['time1'])) {
    $time1  = $_POST['time1'];
}
if (isset($_POST['time2'])) {
    $time2 = $_POST['time2'];
}
```

Para resolver este problema, adicione os selects com o name `time1` e `time2`, conforme a sua necessidade.

Ex:

```html
<select  name=time2">
    <optgroup label="TIMES:">
    (...)
</select>
```

O 2o problema está na query feita. Nela só é retornado `time_nome`. Assim sendo, o value nos selects não estão preenchidos.

Para resolver esse problemas é preciso retornar o id do time no select, alterando a query e, em seguida, usar esse id no `value` do select. O nome da coluna usada como `id` não foi indicado na pergunta, mas supondo que é `id_time` seu código deveria ficar:

```php
$result_time = "SELECT id_time, time_nome FROM time GROUP BY time_nome";
```

E em seguida:

```php
<option value="<?php echo $rows_time['id_time']; ?>"><?php echo $rows_time['time_nome']; ?></option>
```

Comment: Dias, tinha o name, foi apenas um erro após inserir a pergunta aqui. Realizei as alterações no select e no option como você mencionou acima, mas infelizmente continua sem ir os dados. ):

Comment: @matword corrije então na pergunta e verifique novamente que não há qualquer outra diferença. Pode haver vários erros, não senso os q eu apontei oa únicos.